# gnuplot: How to Correlate Points on two graphs

Tags: gnuplot

A quick question about a gnuplot.
I have two graphs, ploted from file, like this:

```
plot "t2" using 1:75 with linespoints title "crop 20",\
"t2" using 1:11 with linespoints title "crop 30"
```

Now I want to identify points on both graphs if they have identical height e.g Y coordinate.
It could be a different colour, or a perfect solution would be to draw a line between them.

Any ideas? 
Thanks a lot.

EDIT

Thanks for the reply Sunhwan Jo, method suggested works fine, as long as similar values appear in the same order. See the image 
[image]

Two graphs share several more points in the same height, but its not picked up due to length difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use external program to filter out data points that have same data in two different column (here I've examined if 75th and 11th column has same entry).

```
plot "t2" using 1:75 with linespoints title "crop 20",\
     "t2" using 1:11 with linespoints title "crop 30",\
     "< awk '{if ($75==$11) print $0}' t2" us 1:11 with lines points title "crop 20/30"
```

EDIT:

Okay, above will not work if you would like to show the data points that have same data in different rows. AWK script will be more elaborated. I have tried as below, hope this helps.

Here's test data.

```
0      0.0      0.0
1      0.3      0.6
2      1.6      1.6
3      0.3      1.5
4      0.6      3.6
5      0.3      4.3
6      0.3      0.7
7      5.5      5.5
8      6.6      6.6
9      5.2      5.2
10     8.3      8.3
11     2.7      5.0
12     2.8      8.3
13     3.3      2.8
14     7.9      3.9
15     9.9      7.9
16    15.3     15.3
17    14.7     14.7
18     3.8     18.1
19    18.1     12.1
```

And the gnuplot command (note some obvious difference in column designation):

```
plot 'test.dat' us 1:2 w lp title "1", \
     'test.dat" us 1:3 w lp title "2", \
     "< awk '{ind[NR]=$1; arr1[NR]=$2; arr2[NR]=$3} END{for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) {if (arr1[i]==arr2[j]) print ind[i], arr1[i]}}}' test.dat' test.dat" us 1:2 w lp title '1==2'
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: Good example, I see we are talking about different things here. I need to link points first graph (4, 0.6) and second graph (1, 0.6). X positions can be different. We can assume that no more than one match is exist. Thank you

Comment: Since you would like to identify similar y-values in two different data series, it might be better to go with y-y graph to show the correlation between the two columns.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer using a awk script to preprocess the data is a good method. Here I give a method using only gnuplot. There is a ternary operator--"?:". Uisng this operator you can pick the points with same value out. For example, "plot 'data.dat' u 1:($11==$75?$11:1/0) w p lc rgb'blue'" will plot only the points with $11==$75. I have written the details in my blog. If any question, visit http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/09/manipulate-data-using-ternary-operator.html.

[image]